# Why am I getting an AttributeError

Tags: attributes, os.path

I am trying to execute a command in linux when the file fast_dp.mtz is present. However, I get an attribute error.

```
import sys
import os
import time
import copy
import exceptions 
import traceback
import subprocess
import os.path

from run_job import run_job

if(os.path_isfile('fast_dp.mtz')):
    os.system('fast_ep sad=fast_dp.mtz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out what I was doing wrong. Turns out that in Geany os.path is file command has an "_" (underscore) while my python 2.7 needed a "." (period). I just change that and the program ran fine.